# When I do having PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, having

I cannot understand why. 
Help me please
I have Customer table, that has many orders. So Customer(id), Order(id, customer_id). I want to get all customers, who has less than 100 orders. So I do sql query to postgres(I use Rails and ActiveRecord), but query is

```
SELECT customers.*, COUNT(*) AS c_c FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id GROUP BY "customers"."id" HAVING c_c < 100 OR orders.id IS NULL
```

I have an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "c_c" does not exist
```

Why? How can I do that?

Comment: Can you include the Rails code that generated the query?

Comment: It would be good, if you can provide me rails code to fulfill my task. I want to get all customers, who has less than 100 orders. Customer has many orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query itself doesn't look valid. You can't reference aliased columns from the HAVING clause. Also your COUNT(*) is ambiguous. You can fix by replacing `c_c` with `COUNT(orders.id)` in `HAVING`, and add `COUNT(orders.id)` in the SELECT:

```
SELECT customers.*, COUNT(orders.id) AS c_c FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id GROUP BY "customers"."id" HAVING COUNT(orders.id) < 100 OR orders.id IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

For an ActiveRecord query try this:

```
Customer.joins("LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id").group("customers.id").having("COUNT(orders.id) < 100")
```

Make sure you have a `has_many :orders` defined in `Customer`

Comment: I tied it. I have en error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: You shouldn't `orders.id` is aggregated by a `COUNT` function. In any case, see my updated answer for a solution in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Sorry, I said < 100. It means 0, 1, 2, 99 orders. That is why I use Left join instead of inner join. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks. It works. I tried to use includes instead of joins('LEFT JOIN'). And it did not work. So I published this question here, and you really helped me. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, you would otherwise be able to use `includes(:orders).references(:orders)` to bypass the "Missing FROM clause" error if you were using MySQL or didn't have the `group` condition. But since `references(:orders)` adds each column of orders to the `SELECT` statement it wont work in this case. The solution is to manually specify the INNER JOIN in the `joins` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use c_c in having

```
SELECT customers.*, (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM orders
  WHERE customers.id = orders.customer_id
) AS c_c 
FROM "customers" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
ON orders.customer_id = customers.id 
GROUP BY "customers"."id" 
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM orders
  WHERE customers.id = orders.customer_id
) < 100 OR orders.id IS NULL
```

Comment: It is very big query for very simple operation. I just want to get all customers, who has less than 100 orders. Are you sure it is only way to do it?